# PHP and wowza streaming engine

Tags: php, wowza

iam new to wowza streaming engine and have configured a test server in my localhost. My intention is to upload videos using php and html/javascript to the server. The videos will be stored in amazon s3. What is the best way to implement wowza streaming server to serve those videos to different clients and how will i get all the streaming url generated by wowza of all the videos that i have uploaded. Is there any way to communicate with my php script and wowza streaming server.

Comment: i guess you have to read wowza docs to understand how streaming works in general. You'll need to create so-called wowza application that will be able to stream videos from s3. URLs will look like: rtmp://ip/vods3/.... but better read wowza docs, unfortunately this is required before i will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php and wowza for recodering videos. 
Please check this links :

https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-set-up-live-video-recording
https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-record-live-streams-httplivestreamrecord
Check videos using wowza player :

[install-dir]/examples/WebcamRecording/FlashRTMPPlayer11/player.html